# What is wrong with this conversion to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that converts an integer to binary and everything has worked well save for one thing. I have the binary numbers stored in a list, so therefore I want to join the list together using the `join()` function. This works well too, however since the list is stored as integers I must concatenate an empty string with the binary list (whilst converting each number into a string). By the way, it's nothing to do with the rest of the code because i've experimented this with a standalone program and I still get the same results. The code is as follows:

```
import backwards

class Binary(object):
 binary=[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]
 answer=[]
 def __init__(self,enter):
  self.enter=enter
  if self.enter>256:
   self.alternative()

  elif self.enter<=256:
   self.calculate()

 def add(self,a,b):
  a.append(b)

 def clear(self):
  Binary.binary=[]

 def calculate(self):
  start=len(Binary.binary)
  start-=1
  on=1
  off=0

  while start>-1:

   if self.enter<Binary.binary[start]:
    self.add(Binary.answer,off)
    start-=1
   elif self.enter>=Binary.binary[start]:
    self.add(Binary.answer,on)
    self.enter-=Binary.binary[start]
    start-=1


 def alternative(self):
  current_max=256

  while Binary.binary[len(Binary.binary)-1]<self.enter:
   current_max*=2
   self.add(Binary.binary,current_max)

  self.calculate()


 def __str__(self):
  converted=""
  for i in Binary.answer:
   converted+=str(Binary.answer[i])

  joined=''.join(converted)
  final_answer=backwards.back(joined)
  return joined

a=int(input("Enter the decimal number you want to convert to binary:  "))
b=Binary(a)
print(b)
```

The backwards module is a function I created that basically reverses a string. Basically, THE PROBLEM IS IS THAT if the first two binary numbers start with a 0, it will print every other 1 as a 0 too (so prints out 00000000). I've purposefully returned the joined variable to prove this (the final_answer variable just reverses the string like I said). As mentioned before, it's nothing to do with the rest of the code as I get the same results when I do this by itself. So how do I make it print out properly without mysteriously converting 1s to 0s, but at the same time ensuring that the list is still joined.

Comment: where in the wall of text is the actual problem and question?

Comment: Well I did say that specifically if i have more than one 0 at the start of the string it will print all 0s instead of 1s. So basically the output is 00000000. I'm pretty sure I did mention that

Comment: why dont you just do `bin(54)`

Comment: never head of that- I've only been using python for a couple of months. What does bin(54) do?

Comment: @CrypticWonder bin(54) converts 54 into a string consisting of the binary representation of 54. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin

Comment: You can make it significantly more clear in the future cryptic.

Comment: @Ramchandra Apte I'm afraid if I use a function which already converts numbers into binary, then that will be defeating the whole purpose of me doing this. I'm doing this so i can get better at programming.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Will do, but I have edited the top so it should be comprehensible.

Comment: Why is `answer` a class attribute? You seem to know how to set and use instance attributes, but you have all `Binary` instances sharing the same `answer`.

Comment: Similarly, why does `clear` replace `Binary.binary` instead of clearing instance attributes?

Comment: Yeah they're meant to share the same answer. I wanted answer to be a class attribute. Besides, relocating answer  won't fix the problem, because like i said i've tried this in a stand alone program without OOP and my problem still persists.

Comment: This is not a reasonable way to solve this problem. A big indication is that you have two different ways of doing the calculation depending on if the number is above 256 or not. That makes no sense, you convert this in exactly the same way no matter how big the number. The second problem is that you don't know what classes and objects are. I recommend you to take another tour through a tutorial.

Comment: As a side note, you should read [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to learn about proper Python code formatting.

Comment: I don't have two different calculations on converting it to binary. If you read the code, you would notice that if the number is > 256, I simply call a method which extends the current binary system(basically it'll keep doubling 256 until it's and appending this onto binary until the final digit of binary is greater than whatever the user entered). and then I have the calculate method. The calculate method doesn't really care whether the number is greater than 256 or not (in fact it doesn't care at all) so i don't see where you got the two different calculations from @ Lennart Regebro

Comment: @CrypticWonder OK, two different *functions* then, whatever. The point being that the mere fact that you need to test if it's over 256 or not means **you are doing it wrong**.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I start off with a blank binary attribute and then append it base 2 digits accordingly? To be honest I just performed this from the spot, but tell me the "right way" of doing this anyway @Lennart Regebro

Comment: @CrypticWonder I'm suggesting you don't have a binary attribute at all. One "right way" (there are many) posted. That solution, being recursive, will fail for numbers above 1339385758982834151185531311325002263201756014631917009304687985462938813906170153116497973519619822659493341146941433531483931607115392554498072196837321850491820971853028873177634325632796392734744272769130809372947742658424845944895692993259632864321399559710817770957553728956578048354650708508671, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as is does nothing since it never calls `Binary`.

```
b=Binary   # needs to be b=Binary(200), for example, to be called.
```

I commented out the use of backwards since it wasn't provided and actually call `Binary` with `b=Binary(200)` and `print(b)` and get `011001000`, which is correct for 200, so I'd guess the problem is your backwards module that isn't provided for us to see.

You can just do the following instead of all this code to get the same answer.  `09b` means format as nine digits with leading zeros in binary.

```
>>> format(200,'09b')
'011001000'
```

**Edit**

Found the bug.  `Binary(54)` prints all zeros as you stated.  The bug is in this line in the `__str__` function:

```
  for i in Binary.answer:
   converted+=str(Binary.answer[i])
```

`i` is the actual digit (0 or 1) so if the first two digits are zero `Binary.answer[i]` always looks up a zero.  You want:

```
  for i in Binary.answer:
   converted+=str(i)
```

Comment: Oh sorry when i copied an pasted it I must have left out the print function.

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius. But what I don't get, is that why should Binary.answer[i] look up a zero just because the first 2 digits are 0? Although it's clearly not so, doesn't the initial code still make sense in saying that the whatever i is equal to gets joined to converted? So why would it then look up a zero, isn't it looping through the the digits? @Mark Tolonen

Comment: @CrypticWonder, `Binary.answer` looks like `[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0]` for `54`.  `for i in Binary.answer:` assigns `i` to each value in turn, which can only be 0 or 1.  `Binary.answer[i]` can then only be the first two entries in `Binary.answer`, which for `54` are two zeros, so that's all that will print.  `200` worked because the first two digits were 0 and 1.  If you pick a number where the first two digits were 1 and 0 like `512`, then you'd print ones for zeros and zeros for ones.

Comment: @CrypticWonder, look into an IDE that allows you to set through executing your source line-by-line so you can view the changes to the data and you'll be able to find these logic problems quickly.

Comment: do you know of such an IDE?

Comment: I understand most of what you said, however I still can't understand why that means Binary.answer[i] can only be the first two entries in Binary.answer. Is it because there are only two possible numbers within the entire list? And is the position of i not changing for each digit it passes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37023/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-cryptic-wonder)

Answer (score 2):

```
def binary(i):
    i, n = divmod(i, 2)
    n = str(n)
    if i == 0:
        return n
    return binary(i) + str(n)
```

Comment: distinct homework smell? lol Im just a 14 year old hobbyist programmer. There's nothing homework about it. Besides even if it was homework, it's not as if i'm asking anyone to do the whole thing for me, I more or less managed to do that. My only problem was joining the string together without printing all 0s (I could still have printed out the list by itself though, although it would have looked  something like this: [1,0,2,3] I just didn't want those brackets that's all. @Joran Beasley